# Amazon Bestsellers Rank doesn't appear when my web browser is controlled by automated test software - selenium webdriver (Python)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using selenium webdriver (Python), trying to extract "Amazon Bestsellers Rank" from a list of urls which are for different products in Amazon website. More specifically, each url is for one particular product listed at Amazon. When I open the urls in my web browser manually, I can see the "Amazon Bestsellers Rank" appears in the Product details section like the image bellow:
[web browser opened manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvoGs.jpg)

But when I run my python code and open the same url automatically using selenium webdriver, the "Amazon Bestsellers Rank" doesn't appear on the page, like image bellow:
[web browser opened automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvBdH.jpg)

For an example, here is a product for test: [T-Shirt](https://www.amazon.com.au/OUTBACK-WEST-Tee-Men-Classic/dp/B08T87VT7F/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=tshirt%20men&qid=1628486192&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExNklJT0lQS0VJNFc0JmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMjM0NDU5MUlMOUhMRFg5M0dPOCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUFYTDdFR0w2Vk5YT0Emd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGYmYWN0aW9uPWNsaWNrUmVkaXJlY3QmZG9Ob3RMb2dDbGljaz10cnVl)

I should say sometimes in a very random situation the "Amazon Bestsellers Rank" appears too.
Has anyone faced this issue? and is there any solution for it?

Comment: I don't see a Best Sellers rank available for the T-Shirt item URL that you have provided. Also have you considered the fact that the ranking may be available only for select products and not all?

Comment: See it for yourself - this is when the browser is opened manually - https://imgur.com/a/b5uk7tA

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment demouser123! There is Amazon Bestsellers Rank: 18,350 at this moment when I am writing this comment. Yes, you are right! Some amazon product don't have ranking for some reason. But this particular T-Shirt has ranking. Please try to open the link again to see if the "Amazon Bestsellers Rank" appears.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your image. But in my system I can see the ranking! it's very weird. Can you check to see the url starts by amazon.com.au?

Comment: This is the url - https://www.amazon.com.au/OUTBACK-WEST-Tee-Men-Classic/dp/B08T87VT7F/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=tshirt%20men&qid=1628486192&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExNklJT0lQS0VJNFc0JmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMjM0NDU5MUlMOUhMRFg5M0dPOCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUFYTDdFR0w2Vk5YT0Emd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGYmYWN0aW9uPWNsaWNrUmVkaXJlY3QmZG9Ob3RMb2dDbGljaz10cnVl

Comment: That's a correct url and I can see the ranking here!!! Very weird! Any thought?